# AMPscript LookupOrderedRows() with AND

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I wasn't able to find out or figure out but the page here http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupOrderedRows suggests that we can create an AND clause within lookupOrderedRows. (Be awesome to create filters like that on the fly!) I don't see any directions on how. What we wish to do is filter the results first by a matched GUID code and then by a datestamp.

```
Set @rows2 = LookupOrderedRows("Cars",4,"Horsepower Desc","MPG",Field(@cardata,"MPG"), StartDate > NOW())
```

Does this need the word AND within the script or something else to make sense of the formula?

Comment: So it appears the script was ok, but adding parameters with comparison operators other than "=" will require a Filter so this won't do what I'd hoped in this instance. Still useful in many other ways as indicated in answers below.

Answer (score 2):

To build an AND clause, you just keep adding parameters. Note you can only do a look up against EQUALS, not greater than like in your example.  If you need to do that, you should use ExecuteFilter with a DataFilter

So, it would be something like:

```
LookupOrderedRows("Cars",4, "name1", @val1,"name2", @val2,"name3", @val3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The values are only compared with `=`.

```
Set @rows2 = LookupOrderedRows("Cars",4,"Horsepower Desc","MPG",Field(@cardata,"MPG"), StartDate, NOW())
```

This would only return those whos `StartDate` are equal to `Now()`.